# kinit(v5): Key table entry not found while getting initial credentials

Tags: kerberos, mit-kerberos

I followed following steps to setup KDC & kerberos. Now while kinit facing following issue.

OS - SUSE 11

```
1. zypper install krb5 krb5-server krb5-client
2. Updated krb5.conf with proper realm details. 
3. kdb5_util create -s <kerberos database created. password provided on prompt>
4. echo "*/admin@EMEA.EBS.CORPINTRA.NET" >> /var/lib/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl <provided permission to principals>
5. rckrb5kdc restart & then rckadmind restart 
6. kadmin.local -q "addprinc admin/admin" <creating principal>
7. kadmin.local -q "list_principals" <verified principals>

8. kinit admin/admin@EMEA.EBS.CORPINTRA.NET <initalise>
9. klist

Create kerberos user:

10. kadmin.local    
    - addprinc himansu@EMEA.EBS.CORPINTRA.NET
                (provide passwrd, when prompted)
11. ktutil
    - addent -password -p himansu@EMEA.EBS.CORPINTRA.NET -k 1 -e RC4-HMAC
    - wkt himansu.keytab
    - q
12. ls -lrt himansu.keytab
13. kinit -kt himansu.keytab himansu@EMEA.EBS.CORPINTRA.NET
```

EXCEPTION:

> kinit(v5): Key table entry not found while getting initial credentials